# Randomized complete block design with repeated measures?

Tags: mixed-model, repeated-measures, experiment-design

I have 2 years gas data from corn field. 4 treatments are replicated in 4 blocks. My samples look like:

```
**treatment    block    samplingTime  Year    gas_conc**
  trt1        A          day5        2015     0.5
  trt2        A          day5        2015     0.34
  trt3        A          day5        2015     0.3
  trt4        A          day5        2015     0.25
     .        .           .           .         .
     .        .           .            .         .
   trt1       D          day5        2015     0.25
   trt2       D          day5        2015     0.14
   trt3       D          day5        2015     0.36
   trt4       D          day5        2015     0.44
```

I am treating sampling time and treatment as a fixed variables and Block and years as random variables. And sampling time is repeated over the year. My question are:

Appropriate repeated model (with two fixed and two random variables) that I can use for the analysis in R or SAS?